# Why is my Wii U tablet home button flashing blue?

Tags: wii-u

When my Wii U is off, sometimes my Wii U tablet home button is flashing blue.

What does this mean and is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Nintendo support pretty much [asnwer this](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8054/~/wii-u-gamepad-turns-on-%2F-home-button-led-flashes-when-the-console-is-turned-off)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This usually means the GamePad is showing an advertisement or you have some other notification. You should be able to disable these notifications in the GamePad Quick Start menu settings.

[Link](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8054/~/wii-u-gamepad-turns-on-%2F-home-button-led-flashes-when-the-console-is-turned-off) to Nintendo's support site.